# Oracle SQL utl.unescape and level

Tags: oracle, plsql, navigation, oracle-apex-5

I am using APEX 5 and I've created a Dynamic Navigation List that allows users to create the navigation bar in a management area. This list also, depending on a column, decides if the Navigation Entry has an External URL link, or an APEX link. If it is an external url, it prepares a url in which it passes an escaped full url into iFrame to allow the link to open within the application.

But what I have noticed is when I try to unescape it, via a computation on the iFrame page item, I need to had an unescape computation per level. Is there away around this, as our application theoretically can have anything between 1 to n levels in our Navigation Entry.

As it stands, for a Navigation Entry on the 5th Level, I have 4 unescape computations; 3 that fire Before Regions, 1 that fires After Regions and this is the only way I've been able to get it escaped.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer. I passed the MENU_ID using a PREPARE_URL function in the dynamic list to an Application Item called P000_MENU_ID. My page item on the home page, P100_MENU_TARGET did a simple SQL query to return the MENU_TARGET from my table into the page item where my application item = the MENU_ID. I then had a post-computation unescape on my MENU_TARGET item with unescapes the URL.